# Trying to identify this plant in my garden?

Tags: identification

Had some early season chaos with squirrels taking out a bunch of seedlings. Replanted and transplanted a variety of vegetable plants and have no idea what this is?  Look familiar to anyone?  I live on Long Island, NY.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You might consider using [iNatrualist](https://www.inaturalist.org/), which has a very useful AI for plant identification. (It also is useful for other living things *and* the data you contribute adds to the [Global Biodiversity Information Facility](https://www.gbif.org/).)

That said, many seedlings look very similar for a long time. This year I had a bunch of [volunteer plants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volunteer_(botany)) from my compost that I misidentified as cucumber or watermelon until it became obvious from the fruit that they are pumpkins. (I should have guessed since I tossed several nearly-whole pumpkins into the compost last fall.)

The leaves in your picture look something like [basil](https://www.inaturalist.org/taxa/61399-Ocimum) except they look a little dull. Basil often has a more glossy-looking leaf. If you have basil, it'll be easy to identify by smell. It's been a couple of months now. Perhaps your plant has flowered? If so, those pictures tend to be easier to identify than the seedling. It might also help to know what you had planted to narrow down the scope a bit.